# How can I separate seven wedges evenly

Tags: adobe-fireworks, alignment

I am creating a seven wedge citrus fruit cross section. Is there a trick to getting all the wedges evenly separated[image]? Or do I have to drive myself crazy doing it manually?

I got this far by using a circle and a seven point start shape as a guide.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I am personally useless in fireworks. If you asked for Illustrator, however...

Comment: Oh, and btw, the words you are looking for are _rotate_ and _duplicate_. This thing might solve your entire problem: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/83600?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Don't know about Fireworks, but in Illustrator you might want to check out the "Polar Grid Tool"!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to build one **master piece** that is perfectly aligned vertically and has the center of the circle (e.g. with no fill) still intact. then you can **rotate and duplicate** around this center piece.

Leaving an "uncropped" version of an element around is generally good practice for that reason. Want to change the radius or gap between them later? Same thing. Adjust master instead of starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to quickly separate the existing pieces, you could scale the group up by an amount, then scale each piece back down by the inverse amount using the Numeric Transform tool (CTRL-SHIFT-T). For example, select all of the pieces and scale them to 200%, then one by one scale each piece by 50%.

To have better control over things though, recreating the cross section using seven duplicates of a single symbol would mean you could just edit the symbol and have all of the pieces move symmetrically. There may be a quicker way, but I would make a vertical pair of symbols with one flipped so I can judge the distance, duplicate and rotate that pair seven times, then delete the redundant "twins".